# How can we create same resource in multiple terraform providers?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am using terraform to create Kubernetes namespace. Sample below

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test1" {
  metadata {
    name = local.ns_name
  }

}
```

I am trying to create Blue/Green kind of deployment using terraform following this [link](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-feature-toggles-blue-green-deployments-canary-test). As part of it, I have created two kubernetes clusters now. One of blue and other for green side and there by now I have two kubernetes providers

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias                  = "kubernetes_blue"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  alias                  = "kubernetes_green"
}
```

I want to understand if there is a way, I can have some conditional on the `kubernetes_namespace` such that, depending on the flags `var.enable_green_side` and `var.enable_blue_side`, I can create the same namespace in multiple kubernetes clusters without having to repeat the entire resource block as follows

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test1" {
  metadata {
    name = local.ns_name
  }

  provider = kubernetes.kubernetes_blue  
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test2" {
  metadata {
    name = local.ns_name
  }

  provider = kubernetes.kubernetes_green  
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terraform's model requires that each `resource` block belong to exactly one provider configuration, so there is no way to avoid declaring the resource twice, but you can at least reduce the amount of duplication that causes by factoring it out into a module and calling that module twice, rather than by duplicating the `resource` block directly:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "blue"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "green"
}

module "blue" {
  source = "../modules/bluegreen"

  # (any settings the module needs from the root)

  providers = {
    kubernetes = kubernetes.blue
  }
}

module "blue" {
  source = "../modules/bluegreen"

  # (any settings the module needs from the root)

  providers = {
    kubernetes = kubernetes.green
  }
}
```

[The special `providers` argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/module-providers.html) in a `module` block allows you to give the child module a different "view" of the declared provider configurations than the caller has. In the `module "blue"` block above, the `providers` argument is saying: "Inside this module instance, any reference to the default `kubernetes` provider configuration means to use the `kubernetes.blue` configuration from the caller".

Inside the module then you can just write normal `resource "kubernetes_...."` blocks without any special `provider` arguments, because that'll cause them to attach to the default provider *from the perspective of that module instance*, and each of the two module instances has a different configuration bound to that.

Whether this factoring out into a module will be helpful will of course depend on how much context from the calling module the child module ends up needing. If your `module` block ends up with almost as many arguments inside it as the `resource` block(s) you're factoring out then it'd likely be better to just keep the `resource` blocks at the top level and avoid the indirection.

Comment: Well then I have to take the refactoring route for my existing resources. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

From the question it is not clear why you would require two provider definitions. But for the sake of example we can consider the below common use cases for blue/green deployment:

- target different clusters
- target different contexts

In both cases it will be easier to use a single provider with different provider configuration based on the flag set in variable.

Considering a variable definition like (using a `string` type but a `bool` can also be used):

```
variable "kubernetes_deployment" {
  type    = string
  default = "blue"
}
```

Let's say I want to target different clusters:

- cluster1 for blue
- cluster2 for green

Then the provider could be configured (using `kubeconfig` for example) depending on the value of variable. For this we can use the [ternary conditional](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html).

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = var.kubernetes_deployment == "blue" ? "~/.kube/cluster1.config" : "~/.kube/cluster2.config"
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "mynamespace" {
  metadata {
    name = local.ns_name
  }

  provider = kubernetes
}
```

This will make sure that the resources (namespace in this case) will be created on "cluster1" for blue deployment, and in "cluster2" for green deployment.

This condition can be applied to other configuration parameters of the provider. Example using same cluster but different contexts:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/cluster1.config"
  config_context = var.kubernetes_deployment == "blue" ? "context1" : "context2"
}
```

Comment: The ternary operator approach will not work when I am looking to have two clusters up at the same time. When I want to try out any new upgrade on kubernetes cluster, I will need to bring up the second cluster, test it out and only then start sending traffic to it before dismantling the first one.

Comment: If you treat this project (directory) as a [module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/syntax.html), it should be possible to call this module with appropriate flags multiple times.