# Explicitly use a provider within terraform module

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-aks

I am trying to explicitly call the providers within my module to create a namespaces in both AzureCloud and AzureChinaCloud.
However, I am running into issues while doing so.. Below are my configurations:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.78.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name = "Terraform-rg"
    storage_account_name = "terraformstate"
    container_name = "tfstate"
    subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    key = "prod"
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  alias           = "sub2"
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  environment     = "china"
}

module "helm_ns_creation" {
  source = "./namespace/"
  providers = {
    azurerm = azurerm
    azurerm.sub2 = azurerm.sub2
   }
  applications = var.applications
  geo = var.geo
  ns_values = ["${file("../namespace/values.yaml")}"]
}

-------------------

provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path    = "config"
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = "config"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "aks_namespace" {
  provider = azurerm.sub2
  for_each = {for ns in var.applications : ns.namespace_name => ns}
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "${each.value.namespace_name}"
    }
    labels = {
      name = "${each.value.team_name}"
    }
    name = "${each.value.namespace_name}"
  }
  }

locals {
# get json
namespace_data = jsondecode(file(var.inputfile))
principal_ids = distinct([for principal in local.namespace_data.applications : principal.principal_id])
principal_ids_cn = distinct([for principal_cn in local.namespace_data.applications : principal_cn.principal_id_cn])
get_principal_ids = (var.geo == "cn" ? local.principal_ids_cn : local.principal_ids)
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "global" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "custom" {
  for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.global.id
# scope = "/subscriptions/{$var.subscription_id}"
  role_definition_name = var.custom_role
  principal_id = each.key
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin" {
  for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.global.id
  role_definition_name = var.builtin_role
  principal_id = each.key
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "china" {
  provider = azurerm.sub2
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "custom_cn" {
  for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.china.id
# scope = "/subscriptions/{$var.subscription_id}"
  role_definition_name = var.custom_role
  principal_id = each.key
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin_cn" {
  for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.china.id
  role_definition_name = var.builtin_role
  principal_id = each.key
}
```

When I run the code to create the namespace within two different clouds(china and global), I am getting the below error only for china region.. However, the same works for global:

│ Error: Unable to list provider registration status, it is possible that this is due to invalid credentials or the service principal does not have permission to use the Resource Manager API, Azure error: resources.ProvidersClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="SubscriptionNotFound" Message="The subscription 'xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx' could not be found."

```
with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on main.tf line 18, in provider "azurerm":
│   18: provider "azurerm" {
```

Right now the subscription fails for china provider.. How do I make it work for both clouds(china and global). Please let me know if any additional details are required..

Comment: Hello @pk_dhruv, May I know where is the provider `azurerm.mooncake` block that you have mentioned in namespace defined? as I see china cloud aliased as "sub2"..

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT .. sorry about the error.. I have edited it now.. 
Also I tried without the provider block in resource section with no difference..

Comment: I tried that with no success.. 
I still get the same error..

Comment: `kubernetes_namespace`  is not a part of azurerm provider , its a part of `kubernetes` provider. so, inorder to use kubernetes namespace , you should be using kubernetes provider not azure rm . You can refer this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/guides/getting-started)

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT .. I have updated the code now in my query.. I will need the azurerm as per the above code.. However, this doesn't seem to work and fails with the error message..

Comment: Still I am afraid I am not sure  why are you using azrurerm in kubernetes provider.? AFAIK, you should be using kubernetes config parameters which you will be mentioning in kubernetes provider as its mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042763/how-can-we-create-same-resource-in-multiple-terraform-providers

Comment: For the rest where you are using azurerm resource you can use the azurerm provider.

Comment: That is true.. For namespace creation, I am using the kubernetes provider.. However, I will also need to perform the azure subscription role creations where I'll be using azurerm as a provider.. This is where I am ending up on the error with.. I am trying to explicitly switch over the providers in my module based on the "geo"(china or global)

Answer (score 0):

**For Explanation, I have divided the whole code into 3 parts which i have mentioned below:**

1. Using the below provider blocks, you must have created AKS cluster's
   in **Public** and **China** Cloud .

   ```
   terraform {
     required_providers {
       azurerm = {
         source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
         version = "=2.78.0"
       }
     }
     backend "azurerm" {
       resource_group_name = "Terraform-rg"
       storage_account_name = "terraformstate"
       container_name = "tfstate"
       subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
       key = "prod"
     }
   }
   provider "azurerm" {
     features {}
   }
   provider "azurerm" {
     features {}
     alias           = "sub2"
     subscription_id = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
     client_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
     client_secret   = var.client_secret
     tenant_id       = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
     environment     = "china"
   }
   resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster_public" {
     provider = azurerm
     name                = "ansuman-aks-001"
     location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub1.location
     resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub1.name
     dns_prefix          = "ansuman-aks-cluster"


   .....
   }

   resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster_china" {
     provider = azurerm.sub2
     name                = "ansuman-aks-001"
     location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub1.location
     resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub1.name
     dns_prefix          = "ansuman-aks-cluster"


   .....
   }
   ```
2. Once the AKS Cluster's are created you can use `Kubernetes Providers` and create `Kubernetes Namespace`in both Public and China
   Cloud which will be like below :

   ```
   provider "kubernetes" {
     host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.host}"
     username               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.username}"
     password               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.password}"
     client_certificate     = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.client_certificate}")
     client_key             = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.client_key}")
     cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate}")
   }
   provider "kubernetes" {
     alias = "sub2"
     host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.host}"
     username               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.username}"
     password               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.password}"
     client_certificate     = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.client_certificate}")
     client_key             = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.client_key}")
     cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate}")
   }

   resource "kubernetes_namespace" "app_namespace_public" {
     provider = kubernetes
     metadata {
       name = "my-namespace"
     }
     depends_on = [
       azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public
     ]
   }
   resource "kubernetes_namespace" "app_namespace_china" {
     provider = kubernetes.sub2
     metadata {
       name = "my-namespace"
     }
     depends_on = [
       azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china
     ]
   }
   ```

   As you can see in the **Kubernetes Provider** , I have used
   `aks_cluster_configs` for both Public and China as I am creating the AKS clusters as well , if you are not creating AKS Cluster then you can use `config paths` as well but the concept will be same i.e. one provider for Public and other for China and the same will go for the resource blocks as well.
3. After the above is done , you can use `azurerm provider` for the role
   assignments as below:

   ```
   data "azurerm_subscription" "global" {
     provider = azurerm.sub2
   }

   resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "custom" {
     provider = azurerm.sub2
     for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
     scope = data.azurerm_subscription.global.id
     role_definition_name = var.custom_role
     principal_id = each.key
   }

   resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin" {
     provider = azurerm
     for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
     scope = data.azurerm_subscription.global.id
     role_definition_name = var.builtin_role
     principal_id = each.key
   }

   data "azurerm_subscription" "china" {
     provider = azurerm.sub2
   }

   resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "custom_cn" {
     provider = azurerm.sub2
     for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
     scope = data.azurerm_subscription.china.id
     role_definition_name = var.custom_role
     principal_id = each.key
   }

   resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin_cn" {
     provider = azurerm.sub2
     for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
     scope = data.azurerm_subscription.china.id
     role_definition_name = var.builtin_role
     principal_id = each.key
   }
   ```

**Note:** If you are using `Helm` Provider as well then you have to follow the same concept of Kubernetes Provider there , You can refer this [Terraform Helm Provider Documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs). Please make sure to configure it the same way we are configuring `azurerm` and `kubernetes` providers and use the same way in modules or resource blocks.

---

**I tested the above with the below code in my environment which has AKS Cluster, Namespace and a built-in role & no Custom roles, the outputs are as below:**

**My Main.tf file :**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "sub2"
  subscription_id = "948d4068-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e00a844e059b"
  tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2d7cd011db47"
  client_id = "f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d713a1bb37c0"
  client_secret = "inl7Q~Gvddxxxx-xxxx-xxxxaGPF3uSoL"
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "sub2" {
  provider = azurerm.sub2
  name = "ansumantest"
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "sub1" {
  provider = azurerm
  name = "xxx-ansbal-xxxx"
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster_public" {
  provider = azurerm
  name                = "ansuman-aks-001"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub1.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub1.name
  dns_prefix          = "ansuman-aks-cluster"

  default_node_pool {
    name                  = "default"
    vm_size               = "Standard_D2_v2"
    availability_zones    = [1, 2]
    enable_auto_scaling   = true
    max_count             = 4
    min_count             = 1
    node_count            = 2
    type                  = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "kubenet"
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = "f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d713a1bb37c0"
    client_secret = "inl7Q~Gvxxxx-xxxx-xxxxiyaGPF3uSoL"
  }
  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
  }

}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks_cluster_china" {
  provider = azurerm.sub2
  name                = "ansuman-aks-001"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub2.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub2.name
  dns_prefix          = "ansuman-aks-cluster"

  default_node_pool {
    name                  = "default"
    vm_size               = "Standard_D2_v2"
    availability_zones    = [1, 2]
    enable_auto_scaling   = true
    max_count             = 4
    min_count             = 1
    node_count            = 2
    type                  = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "kubenet"
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = "f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d713a1bb37c0"
    client_secret = "inl7Q~Gvddxxxx-xxxx-xxxx6ntiyaGPF3uSoL"
  }
  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true
  }

}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.host}"
  username               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.username}"
  password               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.password}"
  client_certificate     = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.client_certificate}")
  client_key             = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.client_key}")
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate}")
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "sub2"
  host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.host}"
  username               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.username}"
  password               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.password}"
  client_certificate     = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.client_certificate}")
  client_key             = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.client_key}")
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode("${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate}")
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "app_namespace_public" {
  provider = kubernetes
  metadata {
    name = "my-namespace"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_public
  ]
}
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "app_namespace_china" {
  provider = kubernetes.sub2
  metadata {
    name = "my-namespace"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks_cluster_china
  ]
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "global" {
  provider = azurerm
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "global" {
  provider = azurerm
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin" {
  provider = azurerm
  scope = data.azurerm_resource_group.sub1.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role"
  principal_id = data.azurerm_client_config.global.object_id
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "china" {
  provider = azurerm.sub2
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "China" {
  provider = azurerm.sub2
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin_cn" {
  provider = azurerm.sub2
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.china.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role"
  principal_id = data.azurerm_client_config.China.object_id
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** I have used 2 Subscriptions in Public Cloud Only as I don't have China Cloud Subscription, but it will be same for different clouds as well , just make sure to add `environment` parameter in the `azurerm` provider blocks.

Comment: thanks for trying out this complicated scenario.. Appreciate the efforts.. However, I am able to get things working when the subscriptions are from the same public cloud.. The issue occurs only when it is in different clouds like one in public and one in china..I have the environment added in the provider section expecting it to work.. however, it doesn't work and the subscription is not being read for both china and public..

Comment: Hey AnsumanBal.. We got this figured out.. I will share the answer shortly.. 
Thanks for your efforts..

Comment: sure @pk_dhruv.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved by using conditions within the provider block..

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id 
  client_id       = var.geo == "cn" ? var.client_id_cn : var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.geo == "cn" ? var.client_secret_cn : var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.geo == "cn" ? var.tenant_id_cn : var.tenant_id
  environment     = var.geo == "cn" ? "china" : "public"
  features {}
}

module "helm_ns_creation" {
  source = "./namespace/"
  applications = var.applications
  geo = var.geo
  values = ["${file("../namespace/values.yaml")}"]
}

-------

## data block for reading subscription

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "custom" {
  for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = var.custom_role
  principal_id = each.key
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "builtin" {
  for_each = toset(local.get_principal_ids)
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = var.builtin_role
  principal_id = each.key
}
```

This is all and no alias used for multi-providers. So when the variable geo is china, it will use the variables within provider for china and if not equal to china, it will use the other variables within provider.. This way, the provider is switched based on the conditions and works like a charm..